# Override styles (given by a previous function) when screen is resized with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button in the header of mobile version of a website (<620px). When this button is clicked, it runs my "mobileNav" function which toggles the mobile navigation between "display: none;" and "display: flex;". It works great! However, if I open up the menu when the screen is <620px then resize the screen to be larger, the mobile nav is still displayed (and due to the design of the site, unable to close).

I need to figure out how to revert the button back to the "Off" state. OR override the styles that clicking the button put in place when the screen gets larger (eg. button click makes #mobile-nav "display: flex;", if screen is resized, override the implemented by the button click and make #mobile-nave "display: none;".

Here is a code snippet. The CSS has gotten a bit untidy, but the key notes are:

- "mobile-nav" is "display: none;" on desktop
- "disktop-nav" is "display: none;" on mobile
- "mobileNav" function toggles "#mobile-nav" between "display: none;" and "display: flex;" when button is clicked
- Current "mobileNav" function does not currently "close" the mobile-nav when screen is resized

```js
// SEARCH DROPDOWN--------------------------------------------------

function searchButton() {
  var x = document.getElementById("searchbar-wrap");
  if (x.style.transform === "scale(1)") {
    x.style.transform = "scale(1,0)";
  } else {
    x.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  }

  var x = document.getElementById("searchbar");
  if (x.style.transform === "scale(1)") {
    x.style.transform = "scale(1,0)";
  } else {
    x.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  }
}

// MOBILE NAV--------------------------------------------------

function mobileNav() {
  // Rotate Buger One and Reposition
  var x = document.getElementById("burger-one");
  if (x.style.transform === "rotate(45deg)") {
    x.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
    x.style.width = "40px";
    x.style.top = "15px";
  } else {
    x.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
    x.style.width = "20px";
    x.style.top = "18.4px";
  }

  // Rotate Buger Two and Reposition
  var x = document.getElementById("burger-two");
  if (x.style.transform === "rotate(-45deg)") {
    x.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
    x.style.width = "40px";
    x.style.bottom = "15px";
  } else {
    x.style.transform = "rotate(-45deg)";
    x.style.width = "20px";
    x.style.bottom = "18.4px";
  }

  // Show/Hide Mobile Nav
  var x = document.getElementById("mobile-nav");
  if (x.style.display === "flex") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  }

  // Prevent Body from Scrolling Behind Mobile Nav
  var x = document.getElementById("body");
  if (x.style.overflow === "hidden") {
    x.style.overflow = "scroll";
  } else {
    x.style.overflow = "hidden";
  }

}
```

```css
/*NAVIGATION--------------------------------------*/

.logo {
  width: 75px;
}

nav {
  width: calc(100% - 75px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

header ul {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.mobile-nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

header li,
.mobile-nav li,
.button-wrap {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-right: 1px #334c22 solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mobile-nav li {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: #3f5d21;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mobile-nav li:hover {
  background-color: #ece5d0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #3f5d21;
}

.mobile-li:hover .nav-text {
  color: #3f5d21;
}

.mobile-nav section {
  flex-direction: column;
}

header li:hover,
.button-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #334c22;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

li:hover .nav-text {
  color: #8cc257;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.button-wrap:hover button {
  color: #8cc257;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.nav-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#searchbar,
#searchbar-wrap {
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#searchbar-wrap {
  height: 40px;
}

#searchbar {
  height: 25px;
}

input {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px !important;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
}

nav button,
.searchbar-wrap button {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: none;
}

.searchbutton-wrap {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #3f5d21;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.searchbutton-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #ede5d0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #3f5d21;
}

.searchbutton-wrap:hover button {
  color: #3f5d21;
}

.searchbar-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #334c22;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mobile-nav .searchbar-wrap,
.mobile-nav input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.searchbar-wrap section {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.mobile-nav {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  width: 100vw;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background-color: #334c22;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 998;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.mobile-nav ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.mobile-nav .searchbutton-wrap {
  height: 60px;
}

.mobile-nav .searchbar-wrap {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.mobile-nav #searchbar-wrap,
.mobile-nav #searchbar {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.mobile-nav input {
  height: 60px !important;
}


/*Mobile Nav Button*/

#mobile-nav {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav-button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav-button:hover .hamburger {
  background-color: #8cc257;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#burger-one,
#burger-two {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#burger-one {
  top: 15px;
}

#burger-two {
  bottom: 15px;
}


/*NAVIGATION END--------------------------------------*/


/*MASTER ITEMS--------------------------------------*/

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #3f5d21;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
}

section {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}


/*MASTER ITEMS END--------------------------------------*/


/*TEXT--------------------------------------*/

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.text-small {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #3f5d21;
}

h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.hero h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.hero p,
.section-headline p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #8cc257;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.column p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}


/*TEXT END--------------------------------------*/


/*MOBILE--------------------------------------*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile-nav-button {
    display: block;
  }
  header .searchbar-wrap {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/619b94aa86.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Craft Testing</title>
</head>

<body id="body">
  <header>
    <section>

      <img src="https://www.abettermancc.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/jeep-logo-white.png" class="logo" alt="">

      <nav class="desktop-nav">
        <ul>
          <a href="#">
            <li>
              <p class="nav-text">Gallery</p>
            </li>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <li>
              <p class="nav-text">Custom Shop</p>
            </li>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <li>
              <p class="nav-text">Apparel</p>
            </li>
          </a>
        </ul>
        <div class="button-wrap">
          <button onclick="searchButton()" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <button onclick="mobileNav()" class="mobile-nav-button">
     <div class="hamburger" id="burger-one">
     </div>
     <div class="hamburger burger-two" id="burger-two">
     </div>
    </button>

    </section>

    <div class="searchbar-wrap" id="searchbar-wrap">
      <section>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
          <div class="searchbutton-wrap">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>

  </header>

  <nav class="mobile-nav" id="mobile-nav">
    <section>
      <div class="searchbar-wrap">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
          <div class="searchbutton-wrap">
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="mobile-li">
            <p class="nav-text">Gallery</p>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="mobile-li">
            <p class="nav-text">Custom Shop</p>
          </li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="mobile-li">
            <p class="nav-text">Apparel</p>
          </li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </section>

  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Encapsulate the styles you're adding via JS into CSS classes and just add/remove those via JS. Then change your CSS so that those classes do/don't apply at the appropriate breakpoints.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I will give it a try, but it seems like that would be the same dilemma, only with classes instead of styles. The problem with other solutions that I have tried is they don't override the styles (or classes, if I try that solution) generated by the mobileNav function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix...

As soon as the `resize` event occurs, hide the mobile menu?

That possibly also will occur on portrait/landscape change... But it may be useful too. You to decide.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", ()=>{
  if(document.getElementById("mobile-nav").style.display === "flex"){

    // Use the existing function to close it
    mobileNav();
  }
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/WNQvVme?editors=0011)